# Connect Power BI to BigQuery by JSON key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a Google Cloud JSON key (eg. `z-dexxent-3X5X02-2X5X287f780X.json`) and I'd like to connect Power BI to some specific project/dataset/table in BigQuery using this JSON file.
Please, is there some step by step for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something, if your data is already in big query would use the built in Power BI Google bigquery connector
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery

and if it is not yet in bigquery follow these steps
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json